# Why am I getting an attributeError when calling the random library?

Tags: python, random

COMMENTS:

I'm using the random library on a larger project, and made a simple test file to figure out why it isn't working. When I import it and begin to call it by typing "random.x" it starts to autofill, but when I actually use it (set it equal to a var), it no longer works.

CODE:

```py
from random import *
from math import *

for i in range(100):
    x = random.uniform(2, 5)
    print (x)
```

Console output:
x = random.uniform(2, 5)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'uniform'

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have imported all the functions in "random" library in the first line `from random import *`.
So instead of `random.uniform`, you can just call `uniform(2,5)`